# Why I console.log a Object,it shows object,but when I console Object.value ,it shows undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am sure that the object that I console had that value.
The code listed as follow.

```
addLoadEvent(function(){
    console.log(toObj(1));          //shows an object;
    console.log(toObj(1).name);     //shows undefined;
    function toObj(name){
        var source_json = getCookie(name);
        return JSON.parse(source_json);
    }
    function getCookie(name){
        var arr,reg=new RegExp("(^| )"+name+"=([^;]*)(;|$)");
        if(arr=document.cookie.match(reg))
        return unescape(arr[2]);
        else
        return null;
    }
})
```

[image: What Console Showed]

[image: the object]

Comment: And if you do toObj[0].name

Comment: The square bracket at the start indicates your `toObj(1)` is returning an array. Did you try `toObj(1)[0].name`?

Comment: @krasipenkov  but it isn't an array....

Comment: @Phil oh,it returns an array! my problem solved. Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(toObj(1)[0].name);
```

I think your `Object` is actually in an array;

Comment: yeah,it is an array.

Answer (score -1):

try this one to see all properties of the object:

```
for(var key in toObj(1)){
  console.log(key+': '+toObj(1)[key]);
}
```

You can also try `toObj(1)['name']` to get the name.

Comment: Your first piece of code should store the result of the first call to `toObj()` otherwise, the results might be different on subsequent calls. Also, there's absolutely no difference between `toObj(1).name` and `toObj(1)['name']`

Comment: beside the syntax there is no difference, right. That's why I suggest this code. :)

Comment: and the for-loop?